How to setup ssl on jmx_exporter for kafka running as a javaagent?
I need to secure the port on which the kafka metrics are exposed via jmx_exporter. The latest version mentions ssl support but I'm not able to set it up.

Running kafka on aws k8s cluster
Using jmx_prometheus_javaagent-1.0.1.jar

Config.yaml [Uses certs on the pod]:
lowercaseOutputName: true
ssl: 
  keyStore: /etc/identity/certificates/peer.pem 
  keyStorePassword: /etc/identity/keys/peer-key.pem 
  trustStore: /etc/identity/ca/cacerts.pem

rules:
- pattern : kafka.controller<type=(KafkaController), name=(ActiveControllerCount|OfflinePartitionsCount)><>Value
  name: kafka_controller_$1_$2

Trying to verify the working locally by [Using local certs]:
kubectl port-forward kafka 9100:9100

curl -vk https://localhost:9100/metrics --cacert /etc/identity/ca/cacert.pem --key /etc/identity/client/keys/client-key.pem --cert /etc/identity/client/certificates/client.pem


